# Uninstall from emulator doesn't work

Tags: adb, uninstallation, emulators

I'm doing my first steps with Android. I'm using a Mac, and no Eclipse.

I've installed my first toy application with

adb install bin/*.apk

and verified that it existed in the emulator. Then I made some changes, reran the build, and tried to install again, which brought the error message

```
   pkg: /data/local/tmp/DefaultActivity-debug.apk
```

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

Fine, so I have to uninstall first. So I tried the following:

adb uninstall DefaultActivity
adb uninstall de.rf.DefaultActivity
adb uninstall DefaultActivity-debug
adb uninstall /data/local/tmp/DefaultActivity-debug.apk
adb uninstall de.rf

but all of them just brought the error message "Failure", with no further explanation.

It's not a really big problem, because I can simply restart the emulator and use "adb install ....", but I'm curious: How do I correctly use the "uninstall" command?

My activity looks like this:

package de.rf;
...
public class DefaultActivity extends Activity
{
  ...
}

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to uninstall, when you install an app already installed, you have to use `adb install -r`. (for more help, juste type `adb`)

To uninstall an app, you have to use `adb uninstall package-name` (e.g. `adb uninstall com.example.app`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Strangely I have read through adb -help several times, but somehow always overlooked the (clearly visible) -r switch!!!

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall the package using `adb`, you need to use the package name listed in the manifest, for example:

```
adb uninstall com.shadowburst.showr
```

You might also want to use the `-k` option to avoid deleting the app's data when uninstalling.

You can also uninstall apps from the **Settings** app: click **Apps**, find your app in the list, then click **Uninstall**. This works even if the app was installed via `adb` or directly from an APK file.

By the way, don't use `de.rf` as a package name, even if you own the internet domain `rf.de`. You want the package name to be something *inside* a domain you control, to ensure that it won't clash with another Java package you write (such as another app or a library).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and explanations! Right now I'm just playing around, and I will for sure follow your recommendation and use a more sensible package name when I'm starting to do real work.

Comment: BTW, clicking on "Settings" displays a message box saying "Unsupported Action". Could it be that this is because I'm using an Android SDK which is already a bit outdated (0.9beta)?

Comment: Probably. The early versions of the emulator were a bit rubbish.